# Oops, an error occurred! You are not allowed to access the given folder: "" TYPO3 7.6

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

[image: I am getting this error message]

I installed TYPO3 v7.6 and i have installed media gallery extension. I followed [This](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/fs_media_gallery/UsersManual/Index.html) TYPO3 extension user manual,

on step 5 -> In Filelist click on the Create new album in "" icon in top toolbar or use Create new album in "" from the context menu in file list

I m getting this error Please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The storage is offline, you need to enable it.

```
TYPO3 backend -> List -> File storage -> Edit -> Tab: Access > is online
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer